# Optimal Selection for minimum total sum

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

*This is a problem from competitive programmer's handbook:*
We are given the prices of `k`
products over `n` days, and we want to buy each product exactly once. However,
we are allowed to buy at most one product in a day. What is the minimum total
price?

| Day | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 0 | 6 | 9 | 5 | **2** | 8 | 9 | 1 | 6 |
| Product 1 | 8 | **2** | 6 | 2 | 7 | 5 | 7 | 2 |
| Product 2 | 5 | 3 | 9 | 7 | 3 | 5 | **1** | 4 |

The Optimal Selection is:

- product 0 on day 3 at price 2,
- product 1 on day 1 at price 2,
- product 2 on days 6 at price 1.

which gives us the total of 5.

The solution:
We either do not buy any product on day `d` or buy a product `x`
that belongs to set `S`. In the latter case, we remove `x` from set `S` and add the price of `x` to the total price.

Here's the code from book:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef min
    #define min(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))
#endif

int main()
{
    int price[3][8] = {{ 6, 9, 5, 2, 8, 9, 1, 6 },
                       { 8, 2, 6, 2, 7, 5, 7, 2 },
                       { 5, 3, 9, 7, 3, 5, 1, 4 }};
    int n = 8, k = 3;
    int total[1<<10][10];
    //Buy all products on day 0
    for (int x = 0; x < k; x++) {
        total[1<<x][0] = price[x][0];
    }

    for (int d = 1; d < n; d++) {
        for (int s = 0; s < (1<<k); s++) {
            total[s][d] = total[s][d-1];
            for (int x = 0; x < k; x++) {
                if (s & (1<<x)) {
                    total[s][d] = min(total[s][d], total[s ^ (1<<x)][d-1] + price[x][d]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Output    
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            printf("%d", total[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The problem restricts us to buy only one product a day but the code seems to not address that issue at all (also, we buy all products on first day which is fine). The output is just the minimum for each product available by that day [1,2,1]. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The output is a sequence of 64 numbers packed as a single string of digits, how do you solve the problem from that?

Comment: @chqrlie from what I understand after reading the book, it looks like 1<<k is the product index and column index gives the day. I think all the non zero values on last column are supposed to be the answer for 8th day.

Comment: This is an [unbalanced assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem#Unbalanced_assignment) which  can be converted to a balanced assignment problem, which in turned can be solved with one of the optimization algorithms mentioned at the link.

Comment: The online solution to your problem using the Hungarian Algorithm is [here](https://www.hungarianalgorithm.com/solve.php?c=6-9-5-2-8-9-1-6--8-2-6-2-7-5-7-2--5-3-9-7-3-5-1-4). C code to implement that algorithm is [here](https://github.com/mohammadusman/Hungarian-Algorithm-in-C-Language).

Comment: yeah... I have extreme problems with that book. for something that should be easy to understand it omits too much and never provides the full solutions that can be run in the debugger. currently trying to understand the same algo and it's giving me a headache

Comment: "What am I doing wrong here?" --> Thinking that code from the book solves the problem.

Comment: I mean, it does xD It looks like they had the correct idea but botched it horribly with how much actual code they thought was enough to recreate their logic locally

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica when we are learning we don't exactly have much of a choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution that was provided in the book was incomplete. For the program to return the correct result, all subsets of first day have to be populated but in the book only the subsets containing single element that were mapped to powers of two i.e., the indices `1,2,4,etc of total[][]` were populated which left the other subsets to have value of `0`. This made each of the subsequent day calculation to take minimum value which is `0`.
code in `line 14 to 16`

```cpp
for (int x = 0; x < k; x++) {
        total[1<<x][0] = price[x][0];
    }
```

must be replaced with:

```cpp
  for (int s = 0; s < (1 << k); s++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < k; x++) {
      if (s & (1 << x)) {
        total[s][0] = price[x][0];
      }
    }
  }
```

Minimum Total Sum for each day will be the set that contains all the elements i.e. `total[(1<<k)-1][index of day]`.
With all the changes the working code is:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef min
 #define min(a, b)((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))
#endif

int main()
{
    int price[3][8] = {
        { 6, 9, 5, 2, 8, 9, 1, 6 },
        { 8, 2, 6, 2, 7, 5, 7, 2 },
        { 5, 3, 9, 7, 3, 5, 1, 4 }
    };
    int n = 8, k = 3;

    //Changed to scale with input
    int total[1 << k][n];

    //Buy all products on day 0
    //Changes here
    for (int s = 0; s < (1 << k); s++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < k; x++)
        {
            if (s &(1 << x))
            {
                total[s][0] = price[x][0];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int d = 1; d < n; d++)
    {
        for (int s = 0; s < (1 << k); s++)
        {
            total[s][d] = total[s][d - 1];
            for (int x = 0; x < k; x++)
            {
                if (s &(1 << x))
                {
                    total[s][d] = min(total[s][d], total[s ^ (1 << x)][d - 1] + price[x][d]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Output
    //Changes here    
    printf("%d", total[(1 << k) - 1][n - 1]);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

After quite a bit of time in the debugger I was able to make the algo from the book work. Suffice to say the snippet provided in the book is completely broken.

Most major edits:

1. we will only update a more complex sum if we are updating it from an *adjacent* sum, that is, we do not update a sum at 111 from the sum of 001 or 010. We use __builtin_popcount to find the difference between the current set index and the one we are tryign to update from.
2. we will only update higher order sets if enough days has passed for *prior* sets to be filled.

I *hope* that I didn't make a mistake here(again). If I did, feel free to correct me. I did try to verify multiple inputs this time and this seems to be working.

Note that I am using multiple local variables that are completely unnecessary. I just wanted some clarity and readability.

This is essentially the same algorithm as in the book, but with a set of restrictions necessary for it to function correctly. Without those restrictions it adds up completely incompatible stuff or adds up at the wrong time and ends up not working.

The algo does address that you can only buy 1 item a day in the `sol[xorIndex][dayIndex-1] + currentPrice` part. The sol part being accessed was filled on *previous* days with items *excluding* the one we are adding.

```
int optimalSelection(int products, int days, int prices[products][days]){
    int sol[1<<products][days];
    memset(sol, 0, sizeof(sol));
    for (int x = 0; x < products; x++) {
        sol[1<<x][0] = prices[x][0];
    }

    for (int dayIndex = 1; dayIndex < days; dayIndex++) {
        int allPossibleSetsCount = 1<<products;
        for (int setIndex = 0; setIndex < allPossibleSetsCount; setIndex++) {
            int currentMin = sol[setIndex][dayIndex-1];
            for (int productIndex = 0; productIndex < products; productIndex++) {
                if (setIndex&(1<<productIndex)) {
                    // this is the index of the set WITHOUT current product
                    int xorIndex = setIndex^(1<<productIndex);
                    if(__builtin_popcount(xorIndex) > dayIndex)
                        continue;

                    if (__builtin_popcount(setIndex ^ xorIndex) == 1){
                        // minimum for the prior day for the set excluding this product
                        int previousMin = sol[xorIndex][dayIndex-1];
                        // current price of the product
                        int currentPrice = prices[productIndex][dayIndex];
                        sol[setIndex][dayIndex] = currentMin == 0 ? previousMin + currentPrice : std::min(previousMin + currentPrice, currentMin);
                        currentMin = sol[setIndex][dayIndex];
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return sol[(1<<products)-1][days-1];
}
```

Comment: I will try to make local edits like that. if it still works I will update. Will give me more incentive to do some more testing anyway

Comment: I have made the edits, it seems to be working the same.

Answer (score 2):

The posted algorithm has a time and space complexity of **n.k.2<sup>k</sup>** which seems very expensive and likely to cause a **stack overflow** for moderately large sets.

Furthermore, the output is not very informative and the constraint *at most one product per day* does not seem enforceable.

Here is an alternative approach using recursion, with similar time complexity **n<sup>k</sup>** but a much smaller memory footprint:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { N = 8, K = 3 };

struct optim {
    const int (*price)[N];
    int bestsol[K];
    int bestprice;
};

void test(struct optim *p, int i, int set, int price, int *sol) {
    if (i >= K) {
        if (p->bestprice > price) {
            p->bestprice = price;
            for (int j = 0; j < K; j++) {
                p->bestsol[j] = sol[j];
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (int d = 0; d < N; d++) {
            if (set & (1 << d)) {
                continue;  // constaint: only 1 product per day
            }
            sol[i] = d;
            test(p, i + 1, set | (1 << d), price + p->price[i][d], sol);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int price[K][N] = { { 6, 9, 5, 2, 8, 9, 1, 6 },
                        { 8, 2, 6, 2, 7, 5, 7, 2 },
                        { 5, 3, 9, 7, 3, 5, 1, 4 } };
    struct optim data = { price, { 0, 1, 2 }, price[0][0] + price[1][1] + price[2][2] };
    int sol[K];

    test(&data, 0, 0, 0, sol);
    printf("price: %d, days: [", data.bestprice);
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
        printf(" %d", data.bestsol[i]);
    }
    printf(" ]\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `price: 5, days: [ 3 1 6 ]`

Comment: the algo may be better but it doesn't answer the core problem of the question: that is -  why the algo in the book doesn't work

Comment: @Zeks: the algorithm from the book does not seem to address the restrictions *at most one product per day*. To be honest, I tried to make sense of the code and understand the algorithm, got a headache too,  gave up trying and came up with an alternative solution. I usually do better and write a documented answer stating what the problems are and how to fix them. For example it is obvious that the size of `int total[1<<10][10]` is hardcoded and too large for the dataset, and modifying `n` or `k` will cause problems.

Comment: I actually managed to make the algo from the book work. Will post my edits in a bit.

Comment: @Zeks: You can check if a non zero number is a power of 2 with `(x & (x - 1)) == 0`

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer

replace 1st code block

```
for (int x = 0; x < k; x++) {
total[1<<x][0] = price[x][0];
}
```

by

```
for (int s = 0; s < (1<<k); s++) {
    // total[s][d] = total[s][d-1];
    for (int x = 0; x < k; x++) {
        if (s & (1<<x)) {
            total[s][0] = total[s ^ (1<<x)][0] + price[x][0];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and remove *break* condition from the following code block mentioned in book.

Comment: This seems incorrect: `total[s ^ (1<<x)][0]`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).